# Event emitters on hybrid Angular 1/2 application

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an angular 1.5 application, which I converted to a hybrid application (UpgradeAdapter), to use Angular 2 components.

Between angular 2 components, the event emitter binding works.

However, when I try to do a custom event binding from the angular 1 application.

Angular 1 view

```html
<ng2-component (onLabelClick)="vm.onLabelClick($event)"></ng2-component>
```

Angular 1 controller

```js
class Angular1Controller{
  onLabelClick(event) {
    console.log('label clicked %o', event);
  }
}
```

The angular 2 component emits the event, but the callback function on the angular 1 controller never gets triggered.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes! it turns out that although its an angular (2) binding. We have to use angularjs binding (kebab-case)

in my example it should be, 
<ng2-component on-label-click="vm.onLabelClick($event)"></ng2-component>

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this question which I was able to find out is that even though its a hybrid angular application.

The event binding should still use the old, kebab-case binding. In the examble above, it should be

`on-label-click="vm.onLabelClick($event)"` instead of

```
(onLabelClick)="vm.onLabelClick($event)"
```

Comment: Not working for me. How is it declared in ng2 component class?  
I use `@Output() onBack = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`

Comment: In my case it had to be `(on-label-click)`